# web-mode custom indent setting ignored

Tags: indentation, web-mode

In `web-mode`, indentation for markup gets set to `8` when I open a new buffer.

I have set `web-mode-indent-markup-indent-offset` via customize to `2`. When I check it outside of a `web-mode` buffer, it is set to `2`.

Lines concerning `web-mode` in my `.emacs`:

```el
(mapcar (lambda (plugin-dir)
          (add-to-list 'load-path (concat "~/.emacs.d/plugins/" plugin-dir)))
        '( ;; ... some more plugins
          "web-mode"))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'zencoding-mode)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; ...
 '(web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
 ;; ...
 )

(require 'web-mode)

(mapcar (lambda (file-ending)
          (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons file-ending 'web-mode)))
        '("\\.php\\'" "\\.ejb\\'" "\\.django\\'" "\\.tt\\'" "\\.html\\'"))

(define-key web-mode-map (kbd "C-c /") 'web-mode-element-close)

(defun expand-for-web-mode ()
  (when (equal mode-name "Web")
    (make-local-variable 'yas-extra-modes)
    (setq yas-extra-modes
          (let ((web-lang (web-mode-language-at-pos)))
            (cond
             ((equal web-lang "html")       '(html-mode))
             ((equal web-lang "css")        '(css-mode))
             ((equal web-lang "javascript") '(javascript-mode))
             )))))

(add-hook 'yas-before-expand-snippet-hook 'expand-for-web-mode)
```

Furthermore, I use `expand-region`. It sets a hook to `web-mode`, but the hook just adds `web-mode-mark-and-expand` to a local `er/try-expand-list` variable.

I have tried a "minimal" configuration, by starting Emacs via `emacs -q` and just loading and requiring `web-mode` and setting the variable to `2` - same result.

Every time I enter a `web-mode` buffer it gets set locally to `8`.

I know I could use a hook like this:

```el
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook
  (lambda () ""
    (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)))
```

To set it to `2`, but that defeats the purpose of `customize`.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `web-mode`? (If not you can try installing it directly from [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode).)

Comment: If you are using the latest version, or if doing so doesn't help, then I suggest opening an issue at the GitHub repo. The author is usually very fast about responding, and getting problems fixed.

Comment: I am using the latest version of web-mode (11.2.2), but my emacs is the system emacs (24.4.1 on LMDE2 (Betsy)). l'll open an issue on github tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does adding `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`change anything ?

Comment: Yes! I changed it with customize, but it works. Thank you. Is that a bug that I should report?

Comment: Likely not, web-mode was likely indenting with 2 tabs, and the variable tab-width was probably was probably a high value like 4 or 8 which made it look wrong. Just a guess though, @fxbois would know better than I.

Comment: I do not understand why ```indent-tabs-mode``` is ```t``` by default

Comment: @fxbois: [just a guess](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle). But seriously, yes you answered my question, but could you elaobrate on the why?

Comment: While this change may be the "right this to do" given `indent-tabs-mode` purpose, [this commit](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/commit/0f1b1bcd#diff-65d99b4476be4737f539e1bc19325383R2200), as far as I know, prevents `web-mode` from respecting buffer local values for `indent-tabs-mode` . It also ignores `web-mode-markup-indent-offset`'s value.